# Grab retweeted status text in loop

Tags: python-3.x, twitter

I am using the python script tweepy to scrape Twitter data; the scraped data is output as a csv. The retweets are truncated. I am looking for suggestions on how I could modify the code below to grab the "retweeted_status.text" if the retweeted_status is "True". It seems that I have to specify: "api.user_timeline(screen_name = screen_name,count=200,include_rts=True)"

```
import sys
from urllib.request import urlopen

default_encoding = 'utf-8'
     if sys.getdefaultencoding() != default_encoding:
     reload(sys)
     sys.setdefaultencoding(default_encoding)

import tweepy #https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy
import csv

#Twitter API credentials
consumer_key = ""
consumer_secret = ""
access_key = ""
access_secret = ""

screenNamesList = [
''
]

def get_all_tweets(screen_name):
#Twitter only allows access to a users most recent 3240 tweets with    this method

#authorize twitter, initialize tweepy
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_key, access_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

#initialize a list to hold all the tweepy Tweets
alltweets = []  

#make initial request for most recent tweets (200 is the maximum allowed count)
new_tweets = api.user_timeline(screen_name = screen_name,count=200)

#save most recent tweets
alltweets.extend(new_tweets)

#save the id of the oldest tweet less one
oldest = alltweets[-1].id - 1

#keep grabbing tweets until there are no tweets left to grab
while len(new_tweets) > 0:
    #print "getting tweets before %s" % (oldest)

    #all subsiquent requests use the max_id param to prevent duplicates
    new_tweets = api.user_timeline(screen_name =  screen_name,count=200,max_id=oldest)

    #save most recent tweets
    alltweets.extend(new_tweets)

    #update the id of the oldest tweet less one
    oldest = alltweets[-1].id - 1

    #print "...%s tweets downloaded so far" % (len(alltweets))

#transform the tweepy tweets into a 2D array that will populate the csv 
outtweets = [[tweet.id_str, tweet.created_at, tweet.text,  tweet.retweet_count, tweet.favorite_count, tweet.author.followers_count, tweet.author.description] for tweet in alltweets]

#write the csv  

with open('%s_tweets.csv' % screen_name, 'w', newline='',   encoding='utf-8-sig') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(["id", "created_at", "text", "retweet_count","favorite_count", "followers_count", "description"])
    writer.writerows(outtweets)

pass


if __name__ == '__main__':   
#pass in the username of the account you want to download
    for i, user in enumerate(screenNamesList):
        get_all_tweets(screenNamesList[i])
        i+=1
```

Comment: Can you give us an example of the code you are using? How about the JSON you're receiving from Twitter?

Comment: @TerenceEden I just added the code. Thank you

Comment: OK, can you please give an example of a tweet which appears to be cut off?

Comment: "RT @taylan1789: O tekme önce Soma'da işçi sınıfına sonra bir otobüste toplumsal barışa atıldı. Tekme hep vardı. Asıl sorun o tekmeyi sahipl…" I believe it's only for retweets

Comment: I edited my post in the case someone has suggestions on how to deal with grabbing the retweeted_status.text

Answer (score 0):

As you've discovered, the way Twitter handles retweets is a little strange.

In the JSON representation of the tweet you have something which looks like this:

`- user: "you"
   - text: "RT @example this text gets truncated at the end of the tw..."
   - retweeted: "true"
   - retweeted_status:
      - user: "example"
      - text: "this text is the full text"`

So, look for `"retweeted":"true"` in the response. If it is there, grab the tweet text from `status->retweeted_status->text`

Comment: Great, thank you. I'm having trouble writing a code that will allow me to do that. If you have any further suggestions, it would be great. Otherwise, I will update my code once I figure it out.

Comment: I edited my post in case you have any suggestions. Thanks.